# JS Passes by reference into a function and can override properties, but can't overwrite whole object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand a complexity someone showed me in JavaScript. Consider the following simple function:

```
function myFunction(p) {
    p.property = 1;
}

var obj = {property: 0};
console.log(obj); // {property: 0}
myFuncton(obj);
console.log(obj); // {property: 1}
```

Let's repeat this, but instead of overwriting one part of the object, let's overwrite the whole object:

```
function myFunction(p) {
    p = {property: 1};
}

var obj = {property: 0};
console.log(obj); // {property: 0}
myFuncton(obj);
console.log(obj); // {property: 0}
```

Why does obj not get replaced here as expected?

Comment: Javascript does not use pass by reference. The Java guys would call it pass-by-value-but-you-have-to-keep-in-mind-that-the-value-you're-passing-is-really-a-reference. I wish there was something less cumbersome; "pass by value" gives the wrong impression and "call by object" or "call by sharing" are too obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does obj not get replaced here as expected?

Because when you call your function you pass a *copy of the reference* to the object `obj`. That means you can *change/modify* the properties of the object you pass to the function but you can't change the actual reference.

In terms of code:

```
// creates an object and a reference to this object is assigned to the obj
var obj = {property: 0};

function myFunction(p) {
    p = {property: 1};
}

// Here you pass a copy of the reference.
myFunction(obj);
```

Now whatever you do is on this copy, like modifying it's property called `property` is reflected to the actual object, since `obj` and the copy of it's reference you pass *point to the same object*. This is what happening to the first case. In the second case you just try to assign a new value to the copy of the reference you passed. So nothing happens to the original reference.

Comment: Thanks - the code example really helped me understand. JavaScript makes my head hurt sometimes.

Comment: You are very welcome :) I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're assigning a new value to a local variable within the function.

The first snippet works because you're modifying an object which you have a reference of. The second doesn't work because you're throwing the reference you have away and are assigning a different object to the variable instead.